# debugging: how to detect part of script being executed through developer tool

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools

I have a text box initiated with the value which on click gets blank. For sure `click/focus event` somewhere is the culprit. but i have huge amount of code and don't know where it is re-setting the value.

Is there anyway in `Chrome Devtool` through which i can find the part of code being executed at time of click on particular element?

Using latest version of Chrome `Version 33.0.1750.14`

Comment: are you looking for debugging javascript using chrome dev tools https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0):

### First try

Go to inspector (Elements tab) and where the CSS is displayed, click on `Event Listeners` tab on top.

### Second try

Go to inspector (Elements tab), right click the `input[type='text']` and `Break on...` > `Attribute modifications` (`value` changes when it's cleared).

Comment: First try did not help but in second try i could not find the `input[type='text']`

Comment: That's a CSS selector for "your text box".

Comment: I just used the first try in a real scenario and it worked well.

Comment: ya i tried but execution is paused on `jquery code` which is i think not the cause

Comment: at last after 3 hours of manual search i found the `position` function conflicting with jquery function. but debugger was unable to detect. but any thanks for your time

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as correct, because that's how you'd go to find an event handler, just in your case it was a little more convoluted.